Need some guidance regarding accessing GRPC server on google cloud run
I have a C# service that listens on GRPC endpoints, which I have deployed to google cloud run services.   I see from the logs that my service is running.   However, I cannot access the GRPC endpoints from my desktop via postman nor my client app.  (edit: I will also add GRPC clients can talk to my service when running it locally or in a docker container).
I can ping the google cloud run instance.  Telenet seems to fail though
matt_raffel@cloudshell:~ (bold-result-421221)$ ping ironbar-bootnode-6iwlqscuzq-uc.a.run.app
PING ironbar-bootnode-6iwlqscuzq-uc.a.run.app (216.239.34.53) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 216.239.34.53 (216.239.34.53): icmp_seq=1 ttl=114 time=0.706 ms
64 bytes from 216.239.34.53 (216.239.34.53): icmp_seq=2 ttl=114 time=0.342 ms
64 bytes from 216.239.34.53 (216.239.34.53): icmp_seq=3 ttl=114 time=0.453 ms
^C
--- ironbar-bootnode-6iwlqscuzq-uc.a.run.app ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.342/0.500/0.706/0.152 ms
matt_raffel@cloudshell:~ (bold-result-421221)$ telnet ironbar-bootnode-6iwlqscuzq-uc.a.run.app 50051
Trying 216.239.34.53...
Trying 216.239.36.53...
Trying 216.239.32.53...
Trying 216.239.38.53...
Trying 2001:4860:4802:36::35...
Trying 2001:4860:4802:32::35...
Trying 2001:4860:4802:34::35...
Trying 2001:4860:4802:38::35...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Cannot assign requested address

I looked over a couple of other posts: here, here.  And according to this post, here, inbound connections should already be permitted.
I believe the GRPC port was correct configured in google cloud run.  Here's what I think is the relevant information from the instance yaml.
ports:
- name: h2c
  containerPort: 50051

If it helps any, the project code can be found here.
What is wrong? And how can I better diagnosis what's wrong?

Are you connecting through TLS?
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift/issues/1501

In my clients, I have tried http, https and grpc protocols (eg http://....).  The server is setup to support http2.  I have not explicitly configured https therefore I would assume its listening for http only.

Cloud Run proxies your container service and exposes it on port 443. So you'll use something like https://{app}-123456789a-rr.a.run.app:443. Your gRPC client may|not want the scheme (https://) prefix.

@DazWilkin interesting.  this is good info.  When I try my client app with https, nothing comes back and http give me an error--I think I might need more logging on my cloud service to get better visibility on that side of things.   Ehen I tried with postman, port 443, I was getting a cancelled and other various error responses (1, 3, 14) until I turned off TLS--and then it worked!  partially, some APIS hang, others return correct/expected responses.  Good info.  Something to go on at least.

Your question lacks sufficient detail to help with further diagnosis. Your service (the service in your container) should be an insecure service because the proxy (sidecar effectively) provides the TLS termination for it. So you should not have any TLS to "turn off".

@DazWilkin I concur.  Digging into it though and will update when I can provide that.  You're help was great as I now have something to work with :)

If your question is still open in a couple of hours, I'll try building your container and deploying it to Cloud Run. I'm gonna take my dog to the dog park soon.

By way of support, I have many gRPC services deployed to Cloud Run and so know that this works.

I cloned, built and ran boot_node.dockerfile locally. It generates errors (Attempting connect to channel is: http://localhost:50051 and my ip is 10.0.2.100) (it should not be using localhost in a container see previous discussion) and I'm unable to connect to it using e.g. gRPCurl.

@tatmanblue please check your email

Copying the answer from DazWilkin comment above, as this answered my question and allowed me to progress my work on this project:

Cloud Run proxies your container service and exposes it on port 443. So you'll use something like https://{app}-123456789a-rr.a.run.app:443. Your gRPC client may|not want the scheme (https://) prefix.

